# Flutter throwing error for null string even though I used await to wait for other function to send data first

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting part of the URL from as the app loads which then sends it to the searchSingleMovie function to call an API to get more information.
My problem is I'm using Future and await but I still keep getting an error. I know why the error occurs (because the value of the string is null in the beginning) but I don't know how to fix the issue. I don't think I can use two awaits together.
Any help will be appreciated. The code and error are given below:

```
Future<List<void>> getSingleMovie(String url,String item) async {
   var response = await http.get( Uri.encodeFull(url), //error here, url is null first
     headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'});

/decode and store the first 20 corresponding movie info in each variable
     setState(() {
       var urlData = json.decode(response.body);
       for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
         if(urlData['results'][i]['poster_path'] == item) {
           picURL = urlData['results'][i]['poster_path'];
           title = urlData['results'][i]['title'];
           releaseDate = urlData['results'][i]['release_date'];
           description = urlData['results'][i]['overview'];
           id = urlData['results'][i]['id'];
           rating = urlData['results'][i]['vote_average'].toDouble();
         }
       }
     });
```

And here is the error:

````
E/flutter (19426): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.
E/flutter (19426): Receiver: null
E/flutter (19426): Tried calling: length
E/flutter (19426): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
E/flutter (19426): #1      _Uri._uriEncode (dart:core-patch/uri_patch.dart:46:23)
E/flutter (19426): #2      Uri.encodeFull (dart:core/uri.dart:1150:17)
E/flutter (19426): #3      HomePageState.getSingleMovie (package:showgrabber/view/HomePage.dart:105:39)
E/flutter (19426): #4      HomePageState.initState (package:showgrabber/view/HomePage.dart:97:10)
E/flutter (19426): #5      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:58)
E/flutter (19426): #6      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
E/flutter (19426): #7      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)```
````

Comment: If you know `url` is null, then you've answered your own question.

Comment: add ?before .length for example movies?.length(). this is to check if the object is null.To guard access to a property or method of an object that might be null, put a question mark (?) before the dot (.):

myObject?.someProperty

Comment: @Abion47 I know it's null and I tried to fix it with await but it worked and it didn't. I detailed the problem more in reply to the post below.

Comment: @Iamnotabot `await` changes a future into a value through asynchronization. It does not magically turn a null value into a non-null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this bit:

```
Uri.encodeFull(url)
```

You say that you know `url` is null going into this call. `Uri.encodeFull` takes a string and converts it into an escaped and URL-safe string to be used as a `Uri` object, and it will throw an error when passed a null value. As such, you are effectively shooting yourself in the foot here.

It's unclear from your code what your ultimate goal for `url` is, so all I can say is to make sure it isn't null:

```dart
Future<List<void>> getSingleMovie(String url,String item) async {
  if (url == null) return [];

  ...
}
```

Comment: My ultimate goal is using the url as a part of the API call I make to get JSON data. The thing is my program runs properly. I think the await makes dart pass that URL again once it's not null (not sure about this). however, it also throws an error when I run the program (doesn't make the program crash but it's annoying to see the error every time and I want to learn to fix the issue.)
So I'm trying to find a solution where if the url is null I want it to wait until I get a value (which it does but doesn't?) It's really confusing because my app works but it shows error in the console.

Comment: @Iamnotabot That's not how `await` works. The `await` is attached to the call to `http.get`, and the only reason it can is that `http.get` returns a future that can be awaited. `Uri.encodeFull` isn't affected by the `await` at all. If you try to await that method you will get an error because it doesn't return a future. The only way for `url` to be null is if `getSingleMovie` was called passing `null` as its first argument. If you want the program to wait until `url` has a value, the simplest way would be to not call `getSingleMovie` until there's a non-null value to pass in the first place.

Comment: Okay, that explains it. I thought http would wait until it got a non-null value before it executes. I made another function to call the first function so it only calls it when it's not null.